# React Navigation headerBackImage not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm using React Navigation 3.11 in my React Native app and I want to customize the back button in stack navigation. In the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#headerbackimage) it says:

> **headerBackImage**
>
> React Element or Component to display custom image in header's back
>   button. When a component is used, it receives a number of props when
>   rendered (tintColor, title). Defaults to Image component with
>   react-navigation/views/assets/back-icon.png back image source, which
>   is the default back icon image for the platform (a chevron on iOS and
>   an arrow on Android).

Here is my configuration:

```
let navigationRouteConfigMap : NavigationRouteConfigMap = {
      _main:
      {screen: page, navigationOptions: 
        { 
          [...]
          headerBackTitle: '',
          headerTruncatedBackTitle: '',
          headerBackImage: Images.backArrow,
        }
      }

    }
    let stackNavigatorConfig:StackNavigatorConfig = {
      headerBackTitleVisible: false
    }

    return createStackNavigator(navigationRouteConfigMap, stackNavigatorConfig)
```

I've got other pages as well in my config, *all* having the same shared navigation options with custom header back image. However, in my app it renders the default back arrow. (`headerBackTitleVisible: false` does work though)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was using an actual image (from `require()`) instead of a React Element. Also, for some reason the navigation options weren't picked up for individual pages either. I've switched to `<Image.../>` and set my object as `defaultNavigationOptions` in `StackNavigatorConfig` and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

this works too

```
headerBackImage: ()=>(<YourAsset />),
```

Comment: thank you. this one solved the issue for me. very simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 5):

Even you can use a custom component, in my case a SVG icon, looks something like this:

```
<LoginSignUpNav.Screen
    name="Login"
    component={Login}
    options={{
      headerBackImage: () => <BackIcon width={25} height={25} />,
      headerTintColor: "black",
      headerTransparent: true,
      headerStyle: {
         backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      },
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you are using Navigation 6.XX.
To work it in 6.XX, try this out

```
headerLeft: () => (
   <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.headerBtnContainer}
      onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()}
   >
     <Ionicons name="close-sharp" size={24} color="white" />
   </TouchableOpacity>
),
```

This should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Button with image

```
headerRight: (props) => (
      <Button
      {...props}
      onPress={() => { /*Do something */ }}
       />
  ),
```